# signalR can't find hub method

Tags: c#, .net, websocket, signalr

I'm trying to write a simple signalR web app.
I have a ChatHub

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void BroadcastMessage(string message)
    {
        Clients.All.writeMessage(message);
    }
}
```

I have js

```
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
        chat.writeMessage = function (msg) {
            $('#mainContainer').append("<h2>" + msg + "</h2>");
        }

        $.connection.hub.start();

        var valll = 0;
        var interval = setInterval(
            function () {
                chat.broadcastMessage(valll);
                valll++;
                if (valll > 10)
                    clearInterval(interval);
            },
            500
        )
    }
    );
</script>
```

chat is not undentified, but I got an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: chat.broadcastMessage is not a function

How can I find part of code which contains error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
chat.server.broadcastMessage(valll);
```

Comment: oh, thanks a lot, that works. Now my server do this method, but dispite it, method 'writeMessage' doesn't work. Why it happens?

Comment: Thanks, I just replace to 'chat.client.writeMessage' and all works!

Answer (score 0):

Have you loaded this in page or header?

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js")"></script>
```